# Create alias for window in AWS Redshift, Window function SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to Alias some windows in some window functions I am using in Redshift.

This is my SQL so far:

```
WITH cte AS (  
SELECT id
      , total
      , COUNT (id) OVER() AS count_orders
      , SUM(total) OVER(ORDER BY period_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
FROM orders
)

SELECT id
      , total
      , count_orders
      , running_total
      , NTILE (4) OVER ntile_window AS quartile
      , NTILE (5) OVER ntile_window AS quintile
FROM cte
WINDOW ntile_window AS (ORDER BY running_total)
```

The error message I am getting is:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ntile_window" Line: 13 Position: 24

It does not seem to run, does anyone know if AWS supports window aliasing? Or where I am going wrong?

many thanks

Comment: please share your error

Comment: The error message I am getting is:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ntile_window" Line: 13 Position: 24

Comment: so - no - i think you have successfully proven that it doesn't allow window aliasing. i couldn't find this in docs.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that's a shame.